# Is safe to reuse plastic bags used for sous vide

Tags: food-safety, sous-vide

Is it safe to reuse plastic bags used for sous vide?
And if it's safe, any special measures apart from the obvious need of cleaning them.

PD: I mean plastic bags specially designated for sous vide that work with a manual vacuum pump [like that](https://www.amazon.es/Rocook-Bolsas-Grandes-Cocci%C3%B3n-Unidades/dp/B071DP2ZKH/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1515163120&sr=8-10&keywords=rocook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not safety issue as long as you clean well. It shouldn't be a problem after most cooks.  If using high heat...or very long cooks, you might check the integrity of the bag.  Otherwise, I suppose you could wash and dry.  I mainly use zip lock-type bags and discard after each cook, simply because they are a p-i-t-a to clean.

Comment: I'd add that it's not just the integrity of the bag that counts, but the type of plastic that it's made of. I'm no chemist, but I wouldn't recommend just any bag just because it doesn't break; the wrong type could still be leaching toxins into the food. Seen for example here https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/a-complete-guide-to-sous-vide-packaging-safety-sustainability-and-sourcing

Comment: I mean, in the link provided in the question the manufacturer itself doesn't recommend reusing the bag...